# "apt install" didn't work but "dpkg -i" did

Tags: debian, packages

I tried to port qemu-related packages ("qemu-system-data,"...etc.) from the Ubuntu disco to xenial.

I downloaded the [qemu-system-data package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/qemu-system-data), extracted it, modified control file and then re-build it through `dpkg-deb --build`.

When I tested it, strangely "apt install" always a success and tell me that 0 newly installed.
Here is part of logs:

```
~$ sudo apt autoremove --purge qemu-*
...

~$ sudo apt install 'qemu-system-data_1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu201911182001.deb' 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
~$
```

And there is nothing new both in `/var/log/apt/term.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log`.
But I can install the package by using `sudo dpkg -i` and remove it by using `apt autoremove`:

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i qemu-system-data_1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu201911182001.deb
Selecting previously unselected package qemu-system-data.
(Reading database ... 259053 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack qemu-system-data_1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu201911182001.deb ...
Unpacking qemu-system-data (1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu201911182001) ...
Setting up qemu-system-data (1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu201911182001) ...

~$ sudo apt autoremove --purge qemu-system-data
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   qemu-system-data*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After...
```

The following is a `DEBIAN/control` of `qemu-system-data_1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu201911182001.deb`:

```
Package: qemu-system-data
 Source: qemu
 Version: 1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu201911182001
 Architecture: all
 Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
 Installed-Size: 996
 Breaks: qemu-system-s390x (<< 1:3.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1~)
 Replaces: qemu-system-common (<< 1:2.12+dfsg-2~), qemu-system-s390x (<< 1:3.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1~)
 Provides: qemu-keymaps
 Section: otherosfs
 Priority: optional
 Multi-Arch: foreign
 Homepage: http://www.qemu.org/
 Description: QEMU full system emulation (data files)
  This package provides architecture-neutral data files
  (such as keyboard definitions, icons) for system-mode
  QEMU emulation (qemu-system-*) packages.
 Original-Maintainer: Debian QEMU Team <pkg-qemu-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: After I change the version number of the package I built from `1:3.0+dfsg-2ubuntuXXXX` to `3.0-0XXXXX`, it works! But I have no idea why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this file in the repository (remote or local) if you want to use apt-get (more information here - https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup). Also you can install it with apt:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/file.deb
```

Comment: really? ever used dpkg to install. deb's?!

Comment: @djdomi sure, but for some reason author of the question wants to use apt-get to install local deb.